# Quotation marks don't seem to work

Tags: php, loops, quotation-marks

I have been working on a piece of code for a webpage and my quotation marks within my php portion do not work.

I got this simple test from w3school and even then it still does not work:

Test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$x = 6;
do {
     echo "The number is: $x <br>";
     $x++;
} while ($x <= 5);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected result:

```
The number is: 6
```

The result I am getting:

```
"; $x++; } while ($x <= 5); ?>
```

It seems to be skipping one of the quotation marks and I cant figure out why.

The link to the w3school test is:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_loop_do_while2

For future reference, why has this been down voted?

Comment: It looks like PHP is not enabled on your webserver.

Comment: Actually, have a look at your browser's page source. You will find that _all_ the PHP code is there, and has been partially mis-rendered as HTML by the browser. Are you actually running a web server? Did you open this as a local file in the browser, or did you visit it via a url like `http://localhost/thispage.php`?  Does it have a .php extension?

Comment: Yes, all the php code is visible. I am running it off WAMP and I am accessing it as a local file in the browser (C/wamp/www/) and yes it has a .php extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the file in your browser like a text file or jpeg which you cannot do for dynamic web pages. You *must* access it via your web server by its URL. Otherwise the web server doesn't handle the file can't process the PHP.